# V-lookup if statement excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, vlookup

To set the context: 2 Sheets, data below:

**Sheet1**:

[image: Sheet1]

**Sheet2**:

[image: Sheet2]

The goal is to extract the data from sheet2 and implement it into sheet1 via a V-Lookup if formula. The data also won't be an exact match (i.e. Dog to Dogs).

In other words: if the name of the animal in sheet 1 matches any of the names of animals in sheet2 then extract the data in sheet2 on average lifespan and implement it into column C in sheet1.

Once I figure out this formula it'll apply to a more complex sheet.

Comment: I suggest you do a "fuzzy lookup". You can either download and install [Microsoft's Fuzzy Lookup Add-In](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15011), or use a Fuzzy Join in Power Query (available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Office 365.

Comment: Alternatively,  sanitise your data, so that the lists _do_ match

Answer (score 0):

Try the following on C2 cell under Sheet 1. Then drag the formula to other cells.

**C2=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!A2&"*",Sheet2!A:B,2,FALSE)**

Note: It will search the string, like **Cat*** in **Sheet 2 Column A**. If it matches (Cats or Cata, or Catalog) it will return the value in **Sheet 1 Column C2**.